# Implementing Simple Tree in Python

Tags: python, oop, binary-tree, computer-science, trie

I'm trying to implement a bit-string Trie structure in an OO-way in Python (I'm only storing 0's and 1's in the Trie, so it reduces to a case of a Binary Tree). I seem to be having trouble with Object passing & referencing. Any help would be most appreciated.

```
class Node(object):
    node_count = 0

    def __init__(self, bit):
        Node.node_count += 1
        self.bit = bit
        self.left_child = None
        self.right_child = None

    def add_left_child(self, node):
        self.left_child = node

    def add_right_child(self, node):
        self.right_child = node

    def __str__(self):
        return "(" + str(self.bit) + ")"

def make_trie(strings, trie_root):
    for string in strings:
        current_root = trie_root
        for letter in string:
            if letter == 1 and current_root.right_child is not None:
                current_root = current_root.right_child
            elif letter == 0 and current_root.left_child is not None:
                current_root = current_root.left_child
            else:
                if letter == 1 and current_root.right_child is None:
                    current_root.add_right_child(Node(1))
                    current_root = current_root.right_child
                if letter == 0 and current_root.left_child is None:
                    current_root.add_left_child(Node(0))
                    current_root = current_root.left_child
        current_root.is_string(string)
    return trie_root

root_node = Node(-1)
test_strings = ['1011', '10', '011', '100', '0']
make_trie(test_strings, root_node)
```

After running this, I get a blank Node in return. I think it has to do with how I'm referencing `current_root = trie_root` in line 3 of the `make_trie` function.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: is `strings` actually a list of strings? Because if it is then this: `letter == 1` or this `letter == 0` will never be `True` and nothing will be added as a child.

Comment: Sorry, that's exactly the problem. Works fine now!

Comment: No problem, I'm going to flag this question for close due to being a typographical error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh wow. Thanks IanAuld, I was being totally silly. I forgot to cast the strings to ints. :(